# How to manage debug printing in F#

Tags: f#

I want to add debug printing to my project with a function having a type signature something like:

```
bool -> Printf.TextWriterFormat<'a> -> 'a
```

i.e. it should take a bool indicating whether or not we are in verbose mode, and use that to take the decision about whether to print or not.

For example, lets say `dprint : bool -> Printf.TextWriterFormat<'a> -> 'a` then I would like this behaviour:

```
> dprint true "Hello I'm %d" 52;;
Hello I'm 52
val it : unit = ()
> dprint false "Hello I'm %d" 52;;
val it : unit = ()
```

The idea is that a command line flag can be used to avoid control this output. I also want to avoid a runtime cost in the "not verbose" case. It is possible to define a function that works like this using `kprintf`:

```
let dprint (v: bool) (fmt: Printf.StringFormat<'a,unit>) =  
  let printVerbose (s: string) =
    if v then System.Console.WriteLine(s)

  fmt |> Printf.kprintf printVerbose
```

but printing/ignoring a sequence of numbers with `List.iter (dprint b  "%A") [1..10000]` (b \in {true,false}) takes amount 1.5s for both values of b on my machine.

I came up with another method using reflection that builds an appropriately typed function to discard the formatting arguments:

```
let dprint (v: bool) (fmt: Printf.TextWriterFormat<'a>) : 'a =
  let rec mkKn (ty: System.Type) =
    if FSharpType.IsFunction(ty) then
      let _, ran = FSharpType.GetFunctionElements(ty)
      FSharpValue.MakeFunction(ty,(fun _ -> mkKn ran))
    else
      box ()
  if v then
    printfn fmt
  else
    unbox<'a> (mkKn typeof<'a>)
```

but here the reflection seems too expensive (even more so than that done inside the standard libraries complicated definition of `printf` sometimes).

I don't want to litter my code with things like:

```
if !Options.verbose then
    printfn "Debug important value: %A" bigObject5
```

or closures:

```
dprint (fun () -> printfn "Debug important value: %A" bigObject5)
```

so, are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like your solution using reflection. How about caching it on the type level so that you pay the price of reflection only once per type? For example:

```
let rec mkKn (ty: System.Type) =
    if Reflection.FSharpType.IsFunction(ty) then
        let _, ran = Reflection.FSharpType.GetFunctionElements(ty)
        // NOTICE: do not delay `mkKn` invocation until runtime
        let f = mkKn ran
        Reflection.FSharpValue.MakeFunction(ty, fun _ -> f)
    else
        box ()

[<Sealed>]
type Format<'T> private () =
    static let instance : 'T =
        unbox (mkKn typeof<'T>)
    static member Instance = instance

let inline dprint verbose args =
    if verbose then
        printfn args
    else
        Format<_>.Instance
```

A pragmatist would just use the fast C# formatted printing machinery instead of this. I avoid `Printf` functions in production code because of the overhead they have, as you point out. But then F# printing  definitely feels nicer to use.

My `#time` results for `List.iter (dprint false "%A") [1..10000]`:

- Original version : 0.85
- Original version with reflection : 0.27
- The proposed version : 0.03

Comment: This is a very interesting suggestion, thanks. It doesn't seem to cache as expected though -- it is slow on the `List.iter` example in my question. I tried adding a Dictionary to `Format` to explicitly cache the functions, but this doesn't seem to work either. Perhaps `unbox` or `typeof` is expensive.

Comment: @robin - I think with the correction above reflection should only be used on the first invocation (per type). However there is still the cost of invoking unoptimized curried closures of the form `(fun x y z -> ()) x y z`, including boxing introduced by `MakeFunction`..

Comment: The key improvement is to avoid the delay of mkKn it seems. With that change to my original version, it is the same speed as your's -- fast enough, I think. I've marked this as the answer, thanks. I think there is still a question about whether it is doing, or should be doing, any caching at the type level.

Comment: @robin, that helps of course but the real key is caching. The benchmark we have been using does not detect the benefit of caching because the code evaluates `dprintf false "%A"` only once. Try this instead: https://gist.github.com/3145242 - you will see my version having an order of magnitude improvement, as expected.

Comment: OK I've tested that and I see your point. Using a for loop, my version caching the functions in a Dictionary comes close, but the type caching is superior.

Comment: @robin type caching is usually preferable for performance and also it is entirely thread-safe. It is not always adequate though. When having to use `Dictionary` special measures (locking, ConcurrentDictionary) have to be taken to make the code thread-safe.

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
/// Prints a formatted string to DebugListeners.
let inline dprintfn fmt =
    Printf.ksprintf System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine fmt
```

Then you can write:

```
dprintfn "%s %s" "Hello" "World!"
```

`Debug.WriteLine(...)` is marked with `[<Conditional("DEBUG")>]` so the F# compiler *should* be able to eliminate the entire statement at compile-time (though you'll have to experiment and check the compiled IL to see if it actually does.

Note that this solution only works if you don't care about changing the verbosity at run-time. If that's the case, you'll have to look for a different solution.

UPDATE : Out of curiousity, I just tried this code (it does work) and the F# 2.0 compiler doesn't compile everything away (even with optimizations on), so the speed is the same whether debugging or not. There might be other ways to get the compiler to eliminate the whole statement to fix the speed issue, but you'll just have to experiment a bit to find out.

Comment: Does "the entire statement" include the ksprintf? Because this function does the costly formatting. Thanks for the suggestion. I am keen to change the verbosity at runtime though.

Comment: _"so the F# compiler should be able to eliminate the entire statement at compile-time"_ >> not quite. The attribute is added, just like C# does, and the method remains, so that you can access the method (type safety etc) in Debug and Release builds. The JIT will then remove the method and the call sites during JIT compilation. It is typically better to mark the whole method, otherwise other parts of the method will still be called. F# _does enforce unit_: a method marked with `ConditionalAttribute` must return unit.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `#defines` just do

```
let dprint  (fmt: Printf.StringFormat<'a,unit>) =  
#if DEBUG
  let printVerbose (s: string) =
        System.Console.WriteLine(s)

  fmt |> Printf.kprintf printVerbose
#else
   fun _ -> ()
```

On my machine the sample test takes 0.002s in the optimised version

Comment: Unfortunately, that approach only allows for a single argument to be passed in. If you see my reflection-based approach, it constructs a curried function accepting an arbitrary number of parameters. So, your dprint works fine for `dprint "%d" 1` but not `dprint "%d,%d" 1 2`.

Comment: This also does not allow testing at runtime for the debug flag.

Comment: Agreed toyvo, this is not my preferred solution.